# SQL results won't find and match each other in Foreach (PHP)

Tags: php, mysql

I've been having a problem matching SQL results from a database. I know they're all there, because i've manually put them in. I want it so the matching results do not display anything on the page and the non-matching results do.

The main problem is i'm using foreach to try and loop through and match them but the PHP/SQL will not find and match them? To make it more understandable, here's an example: (This is ONLY a part of it)

```
foreach ($db->query($sql) as $row) {
    foreach ($db->query($completedVoteSearch) as $done) {
        if ($done['pollid'] == $row['polllid']) {
            echo "We have a match!";
        }
        if ($done['pollid'] != $row['polllid']) {
            echo "<br/>";
            echo $done['pollid'] . ", ";
            echo $row['pollid'] . ", ";
            echo "<br/>";
            $pollid = $row['pollid'];
            $title = $row['title'];
            $type = $row['type'];
                if ($type == "s") {
                    $type = "radio";
                } else {
                    $type = "checkbox";
                }

            $option1 = $row['option1'];
            $option2 = $row['option2'];
            $option3 = $row['option3'];
            $option4 = $row['option4'];
            $option5 = $row['option5'];
            $option6 = $row['option6'];

            $option1vote = $row['option1vote'];
            $option2vote = $row['option2vote'];
            $option3vote = $row['option3vote'];
            $option4vote = $row['option4vote'];
            $option5vote = $row['option5vote'];
            $option6vote = $row['option6vote'];

            $option1voteColumn = "option1vote";
            $option2voteColumn = "option2vote";
            $option3voteColumn = "option3vote";
            $option4voteColumn = "option4vote";
            $option5voteColumn = "option5vote";
            $option6voteColumn = "option6vote";
        }
    }
```

The problem is the "We have a match!" is not being echoed any amount of times in the page, even though there are two matches in the database (76 and 26).

I know it's picking them both up because i've done a test echoing both of the arrays out. and it's saying "76, 76," and "26, 26," in the actual webpage.

Any help fixing this issue im having would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you mean

```
 if ($done['pollid'] == $row['polllid']) <-- three l's?
```

and not

```
 if ($done['pollid'] == $row['pollid'])
```

since you're, later in the code, are using

```
 echo $row['pollid']
```

Comment: What's the difference between those two if statements?

Comment: @ConorReid look at the spelling of pollid. You put 3 l's in.

Comment: Ahaha! Still couldn't notice it when you were pointing it out! :) Best answer!